# GIMP treats pen-down as right click

Tags: windows-7, gimp, graphics-tablet

on my tablet, GIMP treats the pen tip being pressed down as a right click. I can't draw at all with it like this,and the configuration for it lists the pen tip being assigned to left-click. so why does it drag and bring up the context menu each time, and how can I fix it?
it used to work fine on XP, and even on 7 for some time but recently started this strange behavior.

tablet:WP5540